# How can I insert blank spaces into displayquote text?

Tags: spacing, quotation

I'm using `displayquote` and `texttt` to write a piece of software code in a LaTeX document:

```
\begin{displayquote}
\texttt{install.packages("ggplot2",}
\texttt{repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")}
\end{displayquote}
```

which results into this text in the pdf document:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", 
repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

I would like to move the 2nd line a bit to the right, this way:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", 
   repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

but I cannot find a way to insert some blank spaces near the word `repos`. I tried with `\hspace{1cm}`, with `$\;\;\;$`, with `\indent`, but nothing worked.
Does anybody know how to insert these blank spaces?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `\quad` or `\qquad`?

Comment: @Ingmar I just tried, it did not work. Thanks anyway

Comment: or maybe \hpantom

Comment: @riccs_0x Do you mean `\phantom`? It worked but it removed the first letter of `repos`, that now became `epos`

Comment: @DavideChicco.it, no I mean the \hphantom as far as I remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to end the first line with `\\`. Then `\hspace*{1cm}` (note the asterisk) will work.

```
\begin{displayquote}
\texttt{install.packages("ggplot2",}\\
\hspace*{1cm}\texttt{repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")}
\end{displayquote}
```

Another solution:

```
\begin{verbatim}
install.packages("ggplot2",
    repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
\end{verbatim}
```

This solution allows you to add all kinds of funny characters that you cannot use directly as in `\texttt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{displayquote}

\begin{displayquote}
\texttt{install.packages("ggplot2",}\\
\hspace*{1cm}\texttt{repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")}
\end{displayquote}

\paragraph{verbatim, left-aligned}

\begin{verbatim}
install.packages("ggplot2",
     repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
\end{verbatim}

\paragraph{verbatim, shifted}

\begin{verbatim}
     install.packages("ggplot2",
          repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```